# Using a PCWSTR in C

Tags: c, windows

I'm attempting to use PCWSTR in C (Compiled with Windows XP Free Build Env w/ DDK) (i know this is old), and I don't seem to understand how to get a string working.

```c
hKey = NULL;
PCWSTR str = L"test";
```

gets me the following

```
 error C2275: 'PCWSTR' : illegal use of this type as an expression
 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'a'
 error C2144: syntax error : '<Unknown>' should be preceded by '<Unknown>'
 error C2144: syntax error : '<Unknown>' should be preceded by '<Unknown>'
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'identifier'
 error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
 error C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'unsigned short [8]'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you've cut too much out. Is there perhaps a missing semi-colon before it? The compiler is expecting an expression, not a statement.

Comment: the line before it is "hKey = NULL;" and removing the PCWSTR line makes the program compile normally.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an ancient compiler that doesn't permit declarations after non-declarations in a block?

Comment: I totally overlooked this, you just saved me from like 10 hours of pain. Thank you so much. Moving the declaration up fixes the problem. I'll mark your answer as a solution after the "accepting an answer" timer ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of C, declarations needed to appear before any non-declarations in a block.

So

```c
hKey = NULL;
PCWSTR str = L"test";
```

would not be allowed, but

```c
PCWSTR str;
hKey = NULL;
str = L"test";
```

and

```c
PCWSTR str = L"test";
hKey = NULL;
```

would be allowed at the start of a block.

Comment: thats a pretty ancient compiler

Comment: @pm100 MSVC never claimed C99 support and certainly not in the XP era.